# Act as paranoid is not recovering records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-paranoid

I was trying to recover an object from my admin mode and it did not work

```
 Admin.only_deleted.first.recover
  Admin Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "admins".* FROM "admins" WHERE ("admins"."deleted_at" IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY "admins"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `recover' for #<Admin:0xa57f10c>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried writing it more like the documentation on github?

`Paranoiac.only_deleted.where("name = ?", "not dead yet").first.recover`

[docs](https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid)

Answer (score 11):

There is now a restore, rather than recover, but its not correctly recovering the dependent records which is a real pain

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why developers did it but i can see the recover method has a  protected visibility.

So you have to call this method from the model, and you can't call it from the outside

Comment: Well my answer is a mistake and i can't edit. You should use "restore" instead of "recover"

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like the problem is active record version, they moved something and that's why is not restoring any records, it is fixed in the newest version.